# Homebrew error when trying to remove Unbrewed dylibs

Tags: terminal, homebrew

Ok, after running this command in terminal 'rm /usr/local/lib/libguide.dylib'

I get the following error 'override rwxrwxr-x  root/wheel for /usr/local/lib/libguide.dylib? '

How can I fix this :S

I'm a newbie to terminal, any help on this matter will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: I've solved this error guys, simply added the following command 'sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local' and now my system is ready to brew :)

Comment: Glad you made it work. But I think your question was not the best fit for SO. I encourage you to post questions about code that does not behave like you think, including context and hints on the reseach you already have done to find tye problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ixe013, I will keep that advice in mind for future questions.